# Issue with showing multiple strings from internal storage

Tags: android, android-studio, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, stringbuffer

I have this project where it displays a persons insurance information using two `FloatingActionButtons` that control `TextViews` and `EditTexts`. I am trying to save this information to the internal/external storage of a mobile device. I have the code its just that when the information gets displayed all the `Strings` get attached as one big `String`. Here is a print screen of what I mean.

[image: As you can see all the strings that should be in their correspondent places are all in one big string that gets displayed in all the <code>TextViews</code>.]

Here is the code that I used for the `FloatingActionButtons` in the java file called `InsuranceActivity.java`:

```
//Saves information on the editText fields
    FloatingActionButton  saveInfo = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.saveInfo);
    saveInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String InsurerNameStr = InsurerNameEdit.getText().toString();
            String MembershipStr = MembershipNoEdit.getText().toString();
            String NameStr = NameEdit.getText().toString();
            String DOBStr = DOBEdit.getText().toString();
            String PostcodeStr = PostcodeEdit.getText().toString();
            String file_name = "InsuranceInfo";
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(file_name,MODE_PRIVATE);
                fileOutputStream.write(InsurerNameStr.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(MembershipStr.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(NameStr.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(DOBStr.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.write(PostcodeStr.getBytes());
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Information Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //Hides EditText and displays TextViews with the information that was saved
    FloatingActionButton showInfo = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.showInfo);
    showInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            InsurerNameEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            MembershipNoEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            NameEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            DOBEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PostcodeEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            InsurerName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MembershipNo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DOB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Postcode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try {
                String InsurerNameStr;
                String MembershipStr;
                String NameStr;
                String DOBStr;
                String PostcodeStr;

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("InsuranceInfo");
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((InsurerNameStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(InsurerNameStr);
                }
                while ((MembershipStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(MembershipStr);
                }
                while ((NameStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(NameStr);
                }
                while ((DOBStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(DOBStr);
                }
                while ((PostcodeStr = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuffer.append(PostcodeStr);
                }

                InsurerName.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                MembershipNo.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                Name.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                DOB.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
                Postcode.setText(stringBuffer.toString());

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you tell it to. You first read the contents of the file into a `StringBuffer`, and then in the lines below, you set each `TextView` to display the contents of that `StringBuffer`:

```
InsurerName.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
MembershipNo.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
Name.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
DOB.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
Postcode.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
```

If you want each `TextView` to display something different, you should read each line of the file separately and display each line's content in the appropriate `TextView`. Better yet, serialize the data in a format like JSON that isn't dependent on writing order and that you can easily query for specific values.

EDIT

In your case, you could try something like this:

```
.
.
.
FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("InsuranceInfo");
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

InsurerName.setText(bufferedReader.readLine());
MembershipNo.setText(bufferedReader.readLine());
.
.
.
```

Of course, this approach assumes that your files will always follow the exact format, always have the right number of lines, etc. If the user happens to create a new line in an `EditText` and that is subsequently saved, this whole approach will break. I probably wouldn't use this in a production app, but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.

(Minor Java tip, variable names should never start with a capital letter; by convention, only class/interface names should start with a capital.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I don't know if I'm asking for too much here but is there any sort of example I could have on displaying something different in each `TextView`, or could you point me in the right direction? I am fairly new at this.

Comment: I don't really know how much more there is I could say. If you want to display something different in each `TextView`, you have to pass a different string to each one via `setText()`. In your case, you'd want to read a line, set that line as the text of the appropriate `TextView`, and repeat. I can try to edit in an example.